# Downloads folder removed from the bottom

Tags: folders, windows

I have a new mac (purchased about 3 months ago).  Somehow the downloads folder isn't pinned to the bottom anymore (I didn't delete the folder, I somehow moved it).  I tried minimizing the folder and then dragging it to the right of the line but the other icons don't move.  Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You can just drag the folder from Finder.

The folders on the right side of Dock are called stacks, and you can also add them for other folders. See [Mac Basics: Stacks](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3739).